# Dynamically identify a Jenkins build

Tags: bash, build, jenkins, continuous-integration

Currently, I am initiating a build by posting a few parameters to Jenkins from a shell script. I need to check whether the build succeeded or failed and I was wanting to avoid using the post build Jenkins script calls (I don't want Jenkins to initiate the running of any scripts on my server), so the idea was to post to Jenkins every 10 seconds or so (while building != false) in order to get the JSON object with the various build parameters. While this is working fine if I know the build number of the build I want to check on, I can't seem to see a good way to dynamically keep track of the current build number and make sure my script is checking on the build it just initiated and not some other build currently running.

Potentially, there could be multiple builds initiated within a short period of time, so posting to `jenkins/job/my_build_job/lastBuild/api/json` just after starting the build and checking the number that way doesn't seem appropriate given problems with race situations.

How can I keep track of a particular build dynamically from a script on my server in order to check the build success or failure of a build initiated from a post called by `cron`? Is there perhaps a way to name a build so I could initiate it with `BUILD_NAME` and then post to `jenkins/job/my_build_job/BUILD_NAME/api/json`?

Comment: What are you using Jenkins for if not to keep track of and manage your builds? Seems like you're going to a lot of trouble to come up with ways to do things that Jenkins already does for you.

Comment: @regulatethis Some of the jobs are not just generic CI builds though, some are specific tags from svn that are getting built on request (the request being the shell scripts post to jenkins), so it needs to be dynamic. This is also the reason why I would like to not have a final build step initiate a script so as to avoid this being called on non-specialty builds.

Comment: Couldn't you have a parameterized build that takes the SVN tag and builds that revision?

Comment: @regulatethis That's exactly what I am doing. So, my question is how do I check on the success of that build dynamically without a post build script call from jenkins?

Comment: I've never looked at Jenkins's API before but what about generating a unique identifier in your script that triggers the builds and passing it along as a parameter to every build it starts. Then look for that as a property of the build in order to keep track of them?

Comment: @regulatethis That would allow me to check if the build I posted to is the build I want or not, but what if it's not? I would have no recourse after false is returned. If I could post to Jenkins for that unique identifier, that would be useful, i.e., name the build with it or something.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different API calls you can make:

```
jenkins/job/my_build_job/api/json?tree=lastBuild[number]
```

will give you either the last completed build or the current build in progress

```
jenkins/job/my_build_job/api/json?tree=nextBuildNumber
```

will give you the next build number - this includes builds that are queued up waiting for resources.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue filed in Jenkins to return the build number in the Jenkins remote API call: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12827. Please add comments there so it can be worked on as soon as possible.